# Simple WHERE clause with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I just started using MongoDB and I have a simple query that's throwing an exception:

```
public static List<WorkflowItem> GetBySubId(string subId)
{
    var query = Query<WorkflowItem>.EQ(x => x.SubId, subId);
    return MongoDbHelper.Db.GetCollection<WorkflowItem>("workflowItems").Find(query).ToList();
}
```

Exception:

> Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class
>   SplitLineCommon.Documents.WorkflowItem.

Why would that happen? Where is MongoDB getting '_id'? Am I just doing a simple WHERE clause the wrong way?

Comment: `_id` is the primary key for every mongoDB document. If you don't provide one when the document is inserted, typically the mongodb driver will generate an ObjectID (12 bytes binary, 24 characters hex).

Comment: I could have sworn that I read that my documents need an `Id` property. Ah... but that's it, I didn't even do that. Let me try...

Comment: That worked. I had to delete all of the documents first because my new Id property is a string, and the auto-generated id was an ObjectId. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And: you can have a string as an id. But it must be unique and it must have the name `_id`.

Comment: If that's the case, why did it work when I named the property `Id`? I don't have any field/property named `_id`.

Comment: Please view all SO questions regarding Id and C#, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228609/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-can-a-field-called-id-not-be-id , there must be some magic done by the driver I didn't know. I'm away...