# Trouble with mongoDB. The property '_id' of type ... cannot use element name '_id'

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

I use ASP .NET MVC4 WebAPI and i have some class

```
public class Recipe
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string _id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [Display(Name = "Cost")]
    public int Cost { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [Display(Name = "CategoryId")]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [Display(Name = "ProductList")]
    public List<string> ProductList { get; set; }

    [BsonConstructor]
    public Recipe(string title, string description, string type, int cost, List<string> productList)
    {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        CategoryId = type;
        Cost = cost;
        ProductList = productList;
    }
}
```

Than i take some documents in mongoDB

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Recipe>("Recipes");
var doc = collection.FindAllAs<Recipe>(); // exception
```

Why i get this Exception

"The property '_id' of type 'CourseServer.Models.Recipe' cannot use element name '_id' because it is already being used by property '_id'."

I have class Person where i use same attributes and it works.

```
public class Person
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string _id { get; set; } // and other some fields
```

Answer (score 3):

_id is reserved by MongoDb.
Try using "Id" instead.

Comment: Doesn't work. I use attributes [BsonId] and
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]

this is equal public ObjectId _id and Mongo know that my field is the system ID of the document. If I delete this field i get same exception in field "Title"

Comment: Here's part of a class that I'm using in Mongo that's working for me that has an Id. I hope this helps. (Sorry about the formatting.)

    public class Employee : IMongoDataModel, IEmployee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
            Gender = Gender.Unknown;
        }

        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

i think that your class should look something like this :

```
[DataContract]
    public class Recipe
    {
        public Recipe()
        {
            Title = "";
            Description = "";
            CategoryId = "";
            Cost = cost;
            ProductList = new List<string>();
        }

        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id.ToString(); }
            set { _id = ObjectId.Parse(value); }
        }    

        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Cost { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<string> ProductList { get; set; }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried including also the Bson Element Name
Sample on you code you have declare on you model

```
[BsonElement("ProductList")]

[Display(Name = "ProductList")]

public List<string> ProductList { get; set; }
```

Also for reference, kindly check this out https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-crud-operation-using-asp-net-mvc-and-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

Doug Johnson is correct. Check this out and you should be able to make the adjustment.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/NXrED5i7Imo

[MongoDB c# driver - Can a field called Id not be Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228609/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-can-a-field-called-id-not-be-id)